# Trackpad Buttons on 2012 Samsung Series 9 Not Working Properly, appears to double click and doesn't have right click

Tags: unity, touchpad, multi-touch, samsung

These buttons work fine in Windows, but not in Ubuntu 12.04. The buttons are part of the trackpad itself so I figure that's what's causing the problems, but is there any way to get Ubuntu to support this type of touchpad?

The left click button works, but it double clicks. For instance, if I click a link with ctrl held down, it opens two new tabs. Right button doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

This clickpad requires some manual Xorg configuration in order to get right and middle clicking to work properly.

Create a new file called */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/52-synaptics-np900x3b.conf*. 
Inside paste the following:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "np900x3b clickpad"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        # Enable the clickpad and set click actions
        # Single click = left button
        # Two-finger click = right button
        # Three-finger click = middle button
        Option          "ClickPad"      "1"
        Option          "ClickFinger1"  "1"
        Option          "ClickFinger2"  "3"
        Option          "ClickFinger3"  "2"
EndSection
```

Then log out and log in.  You should now be able to right click by using two fingers, and middle click with three fingers.  I have not experienced the one-finger double-click problem that you describe.  If this configuration doesn't fix it, you could also add the option

`Option         "SHMConfig"     "True"`

Then you can try debugging with `synclient -m 1` which will give you feedback on what the touchpad driver is seeing.

More information about this fix and other issues are available at the [Series 9 Community Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SamsungSeries9)

Answer (score -1):

I think the series-9 13" keyboard layout mistakes are fatal, though the series-9 15" is such a unique and slim machine it'll probably sell like hotcakes despite the issues...